# Relation between ANOVA and t-test?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, anova, t-test

In a course I'm currently taking, I learned that if you do an F-test (where $F = MS_{B}/MS_W$), when you have 2 treatments and 1 factor, then this is basically like performing a 2 sample t-test, where the pooled variance estimator is $s_p^2$ (assuming a balanced experiment).

This seems to make sense to me. However, I don't understand why in this case $MS_W = s_p^2$? Again, it makes intuitive sense but I wasn't able to get the math to work out. I plugged in the definition of $MS_E$ and had an extra $(n-1)$ factor, preventing me from showing the equivalence to $s_p^2$. Can someone show how this actually works out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand $MS_B$ and $MS_W$ to imply the mean-squared error *between* and *within* groups (i.e. treatments) respectively, or $MS_W$ is proportional to  $\sum (\hat{Y} - E(Y))^2$ and $MS_B$ is proportional to $\sum (Y-\hat{Y})^2$ which is also be proportional to $s^2_p$. Recognize that both ANOVA and the $t$-test treat $\hat{Y}$ as a prediction of the mean treatment response in either group... I may have this backwards, between/within isn't my preferred terminology.

The degrees of freedom correction should be a factor of $(n-2)$ for both the equal-variance t-test and the ANOVA. You say that you "plugged in" a definition of mean squared error. A $(n-1)$ DF correction arises from only one mean, like from a paired or one sample test. You are estimating two means, I think this is your mistake.